# How do I make jQuery active state navigation work with URLs containing strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I have setup a jQuery Active State Navigation but I'm having troubles to have the Active State functioning properly when there is strings included in he URL. The active state works properly when the URL contains no string (i.e ?LinkID=en) but most of my urls contains strings for tracking sources.

I have setup a commented clean demo so you can have a look.

[Click here for the demo](http://lyesdehili.com/Categories/Coats.html)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `window.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href` since it gives the path without query string

```
$(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 2);
    target = $('#menu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
    $(target).addClass('active');
});
```

---

Try

```
$(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var page = pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/)[1];
    var target = $('#menu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
    $(target).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works but let's say this piece of code is to be included in for dynamic generated content, if I go to page 2 of the highlighted page then I will get a URL that looks look like : lyesdehili.com/Categories/Laura.html/2, how to make it work so it recognize /2 as part of Laura.html hence keep the button highlighted. *The active state won't work on page /2.

Comment: @LyesD whether all the pages has the extension .html

Comment: No they have .aspx extension, I will try your code and get back to you.

Comment: @LyesD try `$(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var page = pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/)[1]
    var target = $('#menu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
    $(target).addClass('active');
});`

Comment: I've added your last code without success, please have a look at the code in production mode http://www.laura.ca/Categories/898-Winter-2014-Laura-Plus.aspx/

Comment: @LyesD which file is having the script... when I executed it from the console it is working fine

Comment: It's inline in the source code, just click "view source page", let me know

Comment: @LyesD there is a syntax issue ... try `$(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var page = pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+\.[^\/]+)/)[1];
    var target = $('#menu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
    $(target).addClass('active');
});`

Comment: P John Hi Arun, please take a look at my new question asked that's related to the same active state menu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610332/jquery-how-to-make-active-state-nav-work-based-on-same-urls-containing-differe

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 2);
target = $('#menu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
$(target).addClass('active');
```

to:

```
var page = window.location.pathname;
target = $('#menu a[href*="' + page + '"]');
$(target).addClass('active');
```

`window.location.pathname` will retrieve just the path part of the url.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.pathname

You really should include the code as part of your question, so if you change or remove your test page it has relevance for anyone else searching for the same thing.

EDIT:

You could do it in reverse, checking if any of your links match the start path of the current URL.

```
$('#menu a').each(function(index, element){
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf(this.href) == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Tanks mate, you're amazing! I will post my code as part of the question.

Comment: Ok the problem I have now is when I go to page 2 of the highlighted page, I will get a url that looks like http://lyesdehili.com/Categories/Laura.html/2, the active state won't work anymore, any idea why?

Comment: Ok, that'll explain why you had the `url.lastIndexOf('/')` part. See Arun's answer, it should solve it